# Cassandra - Which IP address do you use to connect to a cluster when using a driver?

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cassandra

I have deployed a 3-node Cassandra cluster on AWS (EC2).  I'm trying to connect to the cluster from a .NET console application running on my computer.  The Datastax website provides the following code sample for connecting to a local instance:

`Cluster cluster = Cluster.Builder().AddContactPoint("127.0.0.1").Build();`

I've set cassandra.yaml such that `nodetool status` displays the node's address as the EC2 instance's private IP address.  However, if I use the private address in the `AddContactPoint()` function, the .NET driver returns an error saying that `none of the hosts tried for query are available`.

[image]

Which IP address do you use (instead of 127.0.0.1) in the `AddContactPoint()` function for connecting to the Cassandra cluster in AWS?  The EC2 instance's public or private IP address?  Or something else?

My settings in cassandra.yaml are:

```
rpc_address: 0.0.0.0
broadcast_rpc_address: *EC2's public IP address*
listen_address: *EC2's private IP address*
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the broadcast_rpc_address you would use the EC2's Public IP address as that's the address at which all your clients be connecting. listen_address is used for internode communication between nodes in the cluster.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [rpc_address](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml.html#configCassandra_yaml__rpc_address) and more specifically for your environment the [broadcast_rpc_adddress](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml.html#configCassandra_yaml__broadcast_rpc_address). The broadcast_rpc_address should be your public ip. Additionally look at the [listen_address](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml.html#configCassandra_yaml__listen_address) docs which discuss appropriate values to set in an EC2 e